# Doctrine Invalid Mapping File Exception when trying to generate entities

Tags: xml, symfony, doctrine

I'm creating a entity for my bundle but if i want to generate my entity with `php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App\\VacationManger\\Entity` it shows following error:

```
Invalid mapping file 'App.VacationManager.Entity.VacationRequests.orm.xml' for class 'App\VacationManager\Entity\VacationRequests'.
```

I think i have one problem in the XML file but i dont know where it is.

My ORM XML File:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                          https://www.doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity name="App\VacationManger\Entity\VacationRequests" table="vacation_requests">

        <id name="id" type="bigint" column="request_id">
            <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
        </id>

        <many-to-one field="user" target-entity="App\Entity\User">
            <join-column name="request_user_id" referenced-column-name="user_id"/>
        </many-to-one>

        <field name="dateFrom" column="request_dateFrom" type="date"/>
        <field name="dateTo" column="request_dateTo" type="date"/>
        <field name="days" column="request_days" type="integer" length="3"/>
        <field name="reason" column="request_reason" type="text" nullable="true"/>
        <field name="granted" column="request_granted" type="tinyint" length="2"/>
        <field name="granted_reason" column="request_granted_reason" type="text" nullable="true"/>

    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Comment: are you having the repositoryclass into your entity ?
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\DefaultRepository")

Comment: no i didnt have any enititis i try to generate it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want make a new Entity, this is what you need:

`php bin/console make:entity EntityName`

If you want regenerate one:

`php bin/console make:entity --regenerate`

And then Enter (if you want regenerate the all) or add an Entity like this:
`App\Entity\EntityName`

You cant (or can, but very bad practice and need to reach into the kernel... dont do that...) use a custom folder instead of src... Your Entites should will be inside the folder: `App/src/Entity`, and your Controllers inside `App/src/Controller`, etc...

You can add extra folders to your namespaces, like this (if Entity)

`App/src/Entity/VacationManger/VacationRequests.php`

In this case you add this namespace to the current entity (so in VacationRequests.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\VacationManger;

class VacationRequests
{
// ...
```

Or may you can do (I never tested): `php bin/console make:entity VacationManger\VacationRequests`